# ag-grid row checkbox select. Making checkbox selection equivalent to row-selection

Tags: ag-grid

(What I'm trying to do: you know how you CTRL or SHIFT to select multiple rows? Why not just make it a click toggle without keyboard keys needed?)

I'm trying to make it so that rowSelected event or rowClicked event should always check the checkbox on the left column for the whole row.

And add onto it, so click on another row, adds it on. Click on another row, checks that and selects that row as well.

Click on an already-selected already-checked row... and it should "uncheck" and "deselect".

So... Row select multiple + checkbox multiple, are equivalent.

```
              "rowSelection": "multiple",
              "onRowSelected": rowSelected,
              "suppressRowClickSelection": false,


function rowSelected(event){
    console.log("t1 " + event.node.isSelected());
    if(event.node.isSelected()){
        event.node.setSelected(false);
    } else {
        event.node.setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

Plunker EXAMPLE:

https://embed.plnkr.co/vf0aV6Q0MgA4ZvtzWhFb/

(Plunker example, you cannot uncheck a row anymore)

Comment: Perhaps `"onRowSelected": rowSelected` should be `"onRowSelected": rowClicked`

Comment: I've been trying both. rowClicked and rowSelected are just names of the function. I have the correct function names in the code. The problem is the ag-grid tries to loop through ALL NODES instead of the selected ones and crashes. rowSelected -> select row -> select checkbox -> finish. rowSelected -> unselect row -> unselect checkbox -> finish. I can't establish this logic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved. Basically overriding their default "selection model".

```
function RowClickEventHandler(event){
    if(event.node.isSelected()){
      console.log("deselected");
      event.node.setSelected(false, false);
    } else {
      event.node.setSelected(true);
      console.log("selected, add");
    }

}

var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    onRowClicked: RowClickEventHandler,
    suppressRowClickSelection: true,
    suppressCellSelection: true,
    rowSelection: 'multiple',
    rowData: null
};
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/KHj1lstv9GQncxlX4Gvx?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `rowMultiSelectWithClick` to do row toggle selection on the whole row without pressing keyboard keys.

```js
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowSelection: 'multiple',
    rowMultiSelectWithClick: true,
    rowData: rowData
};
```